# Synergy and ElementaryOS

Tags: elementary-os, synergy

I am trying to install synergy from [here](http://synergy-project.org/download/free/). When I run it I get the error:

```
system tray unavailable, quitting
```

I am running Freya.

Any help would be appreciated or the name of different software to share my mouse and keyboard with a Windows machine.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same issue.  I am using Windows 8 as my server, and Elementary OS as the client.  Not sure if your setup is the same.

I used the Synergy command-line commands to start it in a Screen session;

I installed Screen (sudo apt-get install screen).  Then I opened a Screen session using "screen -S synergy", and named it synergy so I knew what the screen session was for.

Then I ran the following command to start Synergy: `synergyc -n NAME OF ELEMENTARY OS COMPUTER -f NAME OF SERVER`.

I then closed my Screen session using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

Screen manual page found [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/screen). Really the only tags you need is -S then the name, and -r to reattach the screen.

The synergy client commands are found [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/synergyc.1.html).

Answer (score 0):

The version from apt-get (1.4.12) in Freya should be working fine - just do `sudo apt-get install synergy`

Answer (score 0):

The last time i checked (probably around august 2015) the version of synergy available from the repo was ancient.. i got version 1.7.4 compiled, but 1.7.5 throws an error at me and doesnt actually compile the synergy executable.. but anyway, i got 1.7.4 easily running on eOS Freya by sudo apt-get installing synergy for the dependencies, but just using my compiled 1.7.4 version autostarted at boot.

i havent even checked the changelog for 1.7.5 yet, but i have an issue with the client randomly disconnecting from the server even though the log says its still connected, tried on 2 different versions of ubuntu, but it works on windows.. i donno

Answer (score 0):

try installing sni-qt:

```
sudo apt-get install sni-qt
```

Comment: This solution worked for me.